# Creating non-unique index on Foreign Key Constraint Column

Tags: database, oracle, indexing

I have a bunch of FK constraints on a few tables on a database. But these FK columns are not indexed.

While creating an index, does it matter which index I create - Unique or Non-Unique?

Does creating a non-unique index have any impact on such columns referred by Foreign Key Constraints?

Answer (score 2):

> Indexes can be unique or non-unique. Unique indexes guarantee that no two rows of a table have duplicate values in the key column (or columns). Non-unique indexes do not impose this restriction on the column values.

So it depends on which data you want to store in FK columns - unique or not. 
But often (when you have one-to-many relationship) it is not unique data, e.g. employees, who work in departments - `department_id` is FK, but there are few employees who can work in same department, so this column is not unique.